# Borland Delphi file syntax

Tags: delphi, dfm

I have question about the DFM file syntax. Could anybody tell me what mean the number in square brackets in below code?

```
 object sbtName: TSpeedButton [7]
        Left = 0
        Top = 354
```

Comment: How is this related to C++?

Comment: @VTT Probably because of C++Builder. But the issue is neither a C++ language thing nor a Pascal thing.

Comment: @Victoria: Thank you. That is answer for my question. My question is a duplicate.